# Lodash Debounce not debouncing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to [debounce a function using Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce), and while it's invoking the function, it doesn't seem to debounce it at all. My issue doesn't seem to be the same mistake as what I've seen elsewhere [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306290/lodash-debounce-not-working-in-anonymous-function) or Google (generally, that they're not invoking the function that `_.debounce` returns).

My currently super-simple implementation is as follows (in Angular with CoffeeScript):

```
  s.search = -> _.debounce( s._makeSearchRequest, 1000 )()

  s._makeSearchRequest = -> console.log("making search request")
```

In JS, I believe that's:

```
  s.search = function() { _.debounce( s._makeSearchRequest, 1000 )() }

  s._makeSearchRequest = function() { console.log("making search request") }
```

I run `s.search()` by typing into an input box, and if I type gibberish very quickly, the console prints out "making search request" on every key press, so many times per second -- indicating that it hasn't been debounced at all.

Any ideas what's I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lodash debounce not working in anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306290/lodash-debounce-not-working-in-anonymous-function)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`_.debounce` *creates* a function that debounces the function that's passed into it. What your `s.search` function is doing is calling `_.debounce` all over again every time `s.search` is called. This creates a whole new function every time, so there's nothing to debounce.

So the solution is to remove the arrow and the extra pair of parentheses, and make sure that `s._makeSearchRequest` is defined before you access it:

```
s._makeSearchRequest = -> console.log("making search request")

s.search = _.debounce( s._makeSearchRequest, 1000 )
```

Example (using JavaScript):

```js
var s;

s = {};

s._makeSearchRequest = function(q) {
  return console.log("making search request: " + q);
};

s.search = _.debounce(s._makeSearchRequest, 1000);

// call s.search three times in a row
s.search(1);
s.search(2);
s.search(3);

// call s.search after 500 ms
setTimeout(s.search, 500, 4);

// call s.search after 3 seconds
setTimeout(s.search, 3000, 5);

// timer to show passage of time
var i = 0;
var t = setInterval(function () {
    i += 1;
    console.log(i + " seconds elapsed");
    if (i > 5) { clearInterval(t); }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am confused here, I read that debounce ignores the calls made to it during the timer is running  and when the timer expires it calls the function with the last function call arguments, is that right? if thats right then the above debounce is incorrect, it is invoking all the function calls. @JLRishe could you please help with this?

Comment: @orangespark It's not invoking all of the function calls. If you look at the code and the log output, `s.search` is called five times in the code, but only executes two times. I've just added a parameter to `makeSearchRequest` to demonstrate this more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
s._makeSearchRequest = function() {
    console.log("making search request");
}

s.search = _.debounce( s._makeSearchRequest, 1000 );
```

POC: http://jsfiddle.net/bvaughn/3saj6znk/