# Await not working when pass async function as params LODASH

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, lodash

I created a custom function with params using callback to reuse, but await not working

```
const _debounceSearch = debounce(
    async (callback: (params: RequestParams) => any, value: string | undefined, language: string | undefined) => {
      const data = await callback({ q: value, lang: language });

      console.log('data on search', data);

      return data;
    },
    300,
  );

const dataCompanies = await _debounceSearch(apiSearchCompany, searchValue, languageParam);

        console.log('dataCompanies', dataCompanies);

        if (dataCompanies) {
          setCompanySearchTags(
            data.items.map((item: Company) => ({ value: item.id, label: item.name, checked: false })),
          );
        }
```

I only got undefined result although i pass await prefix.

[image: Result]

Comment: This requires `lodash` to support `async` functions, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `debounce` function itself can be a promise. `debounce(fn)` is just a regular function, but you can make a `Promise` whenever you want.

Maybe checkout, [Using lodash debounce to return a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57508429/using-lodash-debounce-to-return-a-promise)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I finally found a way to fix it, pass option `leading: true`, then it work, thanks so much

Comment: ok, great. i don't know what is your version of `debounce`, but here's the doc, https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce . Seems it only takes in a function and returns a plain function.