# Use debounce in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to implement `debounce` from underscore library within `setTimeout`.

```
setInterval(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){   
    _.debounce(function() {
      console.log('debounce');
    }, 500);
  }, 1000);
}, 100);
```

Basically, `console.log('debounce')` should be called once in 500ms but it seems there's no output at all in the console.

JS Bin for testing: http://jsbin.com/beqisuruwu/edit?js,output

Thanks in advance.

Comment: k.. what is the problem?

Comment: @Gogol no output in the console. So, 'debounce' is not printed out

Comment: did you include underscore library before calling the script? Also, try attaching it to an event.. e.g. window load or something..

Comment: I did include the library, I can get the value of `_.VERSION`

Comment: Ok. try running the script after dom is loaded.. like following http://stackoverflow.com/a/21814964/1437261

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working http://jsbin.com/wogumujahi/edit?js,output

Comment: Ok, it seems that debounce does not support anonymous functions.. see this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/24309963/1437261  basically, define the function and pass it to debounce and see if that works.

Comment: debounce returns a function which is not called in your code. Create the debounced function outside the `setInterval` e.g. `var myFn = debounce(...)` and call it within the `setTimeout`: `myFn();`

Comment: Why use a `setTimeout` and `debounce`? [Underscore's Debounce is a setTimeout](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-83)...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need function after setTimeout? Because _.debounce is a function itself. I am not sure either )) but code below works for me:setInterval(function() {
      setTimeout(
        _.debounce(function() {
          console.log('debounce');
        }, 500)
      , 1000);
    }, 100);